# Azure pipeline fails with Flutter Build windows

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, flutter-windows, flutter-build

I have a azure-pipeline.yml file as below.
variables:
buildNumber: $[replace(variables['Build.BuildNumber'], '.', '')] # runtime expression

```
stages:
- stage: Flutter_Build_Windows_Test
  dependsOn: []
  jobs:
  - template: '../../templates/mobile-application/flutter-build-for-windows.yml'
    parameters:
      entryPoint: 'lib/main.dart'
      buildNumber: $(buildNumber)
```

And here is flutter-build-for-windows.yml file

```
parameters:
    entryPoint: ''
    buildNumber: ''

jobs:
- job: Flutter_Build_For_Windows
  pool:
    vmImage: windows-2019
  steps:
  - script: |
      echo buildNumber : 
      echo '${{ parameters.buildNumber }}' 
      echo entryPoint :
      echo '${{ parameters.entryPoint }}'

  - task: Hey24sheep.flutter.flutter-install.FlutterInstall@0
    displayName: 'Flutter Install'

  - script: |
      $(FlutterToolPath)/flutter config --enable-windows-desktop
   
      $(FlutterToolPath)/flutter doctor
    displayName: 'Enable Windows Desktop Support'

  - task: Hey24sheep.flutter.flutter-build.FlutterBuild@0
    displayName: 'Flutter Build windows'
    inputs:
      target: windows
      projectDirectory: MyApplication.UI
      buildNumber: '${{ parameters.buildNumber }}'
      entryPoint: '${{ parameters.entryPoint }}'
  
  - task: CopyFiles@2
    displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    inputs:
        Contents: |
             MyApplication.UI\build\windows\runner\Release\**\*
             DevOps\Scripts\Flutter Build\**\*
             DevOps\Required_Dlls\*
        TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    
  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    displayName: 'Publish Artifact: Windows copy'
    inputs:
      ArtifactName: Windows-${{ parameters.environment }}
```

When the pipeline runs, It fails in "Flutter Build windows" step and saying that

> Building Windows application...
> D:\a\1\s\MyApplication.UI\windows\runner\flutter_window.cpp(1,10):
> fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'flutter_window.h': No
> such file or directory
> [D:\a\1\s\MyApplication.UI\build\windows\runner\MyApplication.vcxproj]
> D:\a\1\s\MyApplication.UI\windows\runner\main.cpp(5,10): fatal error
> C1083: Cannot open include file: 'flutter_window.h': No such file or
> directory
> [D:\a\1\s\MyApplication.UI\build\windows\runner\MyApplication.vcxproj]
> D:\a\1\s\MyApplication.UI\windows\runner\utils.cpp(1,10): fatal error
> C1083: Cannot open include file: 'utils.h': No such file or directory
> [D:\a\1\s\MyApplication.UI\build\windows\runner\MyApplication.vcxproj]
> D:\a\1\s\MyApplication.UI\windows\runner\win32_window.cpp(1,10): fatal
> error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'win32_window.h': No such file
> or directory
> [D:\a\1\s\MyApplication.UI\build\windows\runner\MyApplication.vcxproj]
> Building Windows application...
> 126.5s Build process failed.

The full log is here;

> Starting: Flutter Build windows
> ============================================================================== Task         : Flutter Build Task Description  : Build a Flutter
> application project. Version      : 0.3.6 Author       : Hey24sheep
> Help         : [More
> Information](https://github.com/hey24sheep/azure-flutter-tasks)
> ============================================================================== C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /D /S /C
> "C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Flutter\3.10.2\windows\flutter\bin\flutter.bat
> build windows "--build-number=202306014" "--target=lib/main.dart""
> Resolving dependencies...
>
> - archive 3.3.7
> - async 2.11.0
> - boolean_selector 2.1.1
> - characters 1.3.0
> - clock 1.1.1
> - collection 1.17.1 (1.17.2 available)
> - convert 3.1.1
> - crypto 3.0.3
> - cupertino_icons 1.0.5
> - desktop_window 0.4.0
> - fake_async 1.3.1
> - flutter 0.0.0 from sdk flutter
> - flutter_lints 2.0.1
> - flutter_test 0.0.0 from sdk flutter
> - http 0.13.6 (1.0.0 available)
> - http_parser 4.0.2
> - js 0.6.7
> - lints 2.1.0
> - lottie 1.4.3 (2.3.2 available)
> - matcher 0.12.15 (0.12.16 available)
> - material_color_utilities 0.2.0 (0.5.0 available)
> - meta 1.9.1
> - nested 1.0.0
> - path 1.8.3
> - pointycastle 3.7.3
> - provider 6.0.5
> - sky_engine 0.0.99 from sdk flutter
> - source_span 1.9.1 (1.10.0 available)
> - stack_trace 1.11.0
> - stream_channel 2.1.1
> - string_scanner 1.2.0
> - term_glyph 1.2.1
> - test_api 0.5.1 (0.6.0 available)
> - typed_data 1.3.2
> - vector_math 2.1.4 Changed 35 dependencies!
>
> Building Windows application...
> D:\a\1\s\MyApplication.UI\windows\runner\flutter_window.cpp(1,10):
> fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'flutter_window.h': No
> such file or directory
> [D:\a\1\s\MyApplication.UI\build\windows\runner\MyApplication.vcxproj]
> D:\a\1\s\MyApplication.UI\windows\runner\main.cpp(5,10): fatal error
> C1083: Cannot open include file: 'flutter_window.h': No such file or
> directory
> [D:\a\1\s\MyApplication.UI\build\windows\runner\MyApplication.vcxproj]
> D:\a\1\s\MyApplication.UI\windows\runner\utils.cpp(1,10): fatal error
> C1083: Cannot open include file: 'utils.h': No such file or directory
> [D:\a\1\s\MyApplication.UI\build\windows\runner\MyApplication.vcxproj]
> D:\a\1\s\MyApplication.UI\windows\runner\win32_window.cpp(1,10): fatal
> error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'win32_window.h': No such file
> or directory
> [D:\a\1\s\MyApplication.UI\build\windows\runner\MyApplication.vcxproj]
> Building Windows application...
> 126.5s Build process failed.
> ##[error]Error: The process 'C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Flutter\3.10.2\windows\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'
> failed with exit code 1 Finishing: Flutter Build windows

Lastly, here is my pubspec.yaml file

```
name: myapplication_ui
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.17.0 <3.3.3'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  provider: ^6.0.3
  http: ^0.13.5
  lottie: ^1.4.3
  desktop_window: ^0.4.0
  collection: ^1.17.1

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/images/icons/
    - assets/images/
    - assets/animations/
    - assets/files/

  fonts:
    - family: MYCOMPANY
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/MYCOMPANY-REGULAR.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/MYCOMPANY-ITALIC.ttf
          style: italic
        - asset: assets/fonts/MYCOMPANY-LIGHT.ttf
          weight: 300
        - asset: assets/fonts/MYCOMPANY-BOLD.ttf
          weight: 700
```

Can anyone guide me to a solution?
Thanks.

Comment: If you're having party with a third-party marketplace extension, the best place to submit bug reports is on that project's GitHub page.

Answer (score 0):

You should add these missing header (*.h)  files to the your project files. After your adding run pipeline again.